# Angular: link two different checkbox from a list

Tags: angular, checkbox

I've been struggling for hours to realise a list where I have two checkboxes dependent on each other.

Basically, I have a list of cars. On some of them, I want to select them as blue or red. If I say on is blue I want the checkbox to be unchecked.

How can I do?

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars |let i = index;"> 
    <td>
        {{ car.id}} €
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="car.id" (change)="onCarBlue($event,i)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="car.id" (change)="onCarRed($event,i)">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: not the solution to the problem, but why not a radio-button instead?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to go about this. The first that comes to mind is storing the color information inside the car object itself. So your car interface would look like this:

```
interface Car {
    id: number;
    color?: 'blue' | 'red'; // This one is added as optional property
}
```

Then, in your html, you can use that property to decide if a checkbox is checked:

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index;"> 
    <td>{{car.id}} €</td>
    <td>
        <input 
           type="checkbox" 
           [checked]="car.color === 'blue'" 
           (change)="onCarColorChange(i, 'blue')">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            [checked]="car.color === 'red'" 
            (change)="onCarColorChange(i, 'red')">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Finally, in your component.ts, you need to react to the change and set the variable:

```
public onCarColorChange(index:number, color: 'blue' | 'red') {
    // Do mind: You need to create a new Array for Angular change detection 
    // to pick up that the color has changed

    this.cars = this.cars.map((car, i) => i === index 
        ? {...car, color} // Change the color of the car at the given index
        : car // Return an unchanged car for all other indexes
    );
}
```

I created a StackBlitz which demonstrates this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1ky1w